# Selenium Firefox Web Driver occasionally not finding an element

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I am using the Selenium Firefox Web Driver to run automated NUnit tests and, seemingly at random, it is not able to locate a particular button.

The function it is using is this

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("createUser")).Click();
```

I can't figure out a pattern to why it does and doesn't work at different times. Does anyone have any ideas as to what is going on or what a possible work around might be? I am not using dynamic ids, and I have

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
```

in place to cause it to wait up to 15 seconds for the page to fully render.

Comment: time of loading the page? Selenium wait for load ?

Comment: page load occurs in plenty of time. It sits for about 10 seconds with the page fully loaded before it errors out.

Comment: what about check if exists another object, if yes then check your button?

Comment: It has successfully interacted with multiple other elements on the same page, the only exception is that the buttons that occasionally aren't working are dynamically created on page load through javascript. But I didn't think that mattered to Selenium.

Comment: Make sure if the element is getting created dynamically that it's Id is not changing each time, I know extJS does this. If that is the case you will want to specify it's id in the class that creates the button. Or you can get the element by another attribute such as name or text.